# Can somebody explain me these paragraphs? It's about the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Tags: calculus

[image]

Why is F continuous at x=a and x=b? I couldn't find the reason for the continuity of F.

Comment: $F$ is the antiderivative of $f$ in $[a,b]$. This in particular means that the one sided derivatives at the points $a,b$ exist. So just use the fact that a differentiable function is continuous. (this works for one sided derivatives as well. If the right sided derivative at the point $a$ exists then $\lim_{x\to a^+} F(x)=F(a))$.

Comment: $F$ is assumed to be an anti-derivative of $f$. In particular, it is differentiable. Every differentiable function is continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Studying the function $$h(x)=\int_a^xf(t)dt$$ you will find that it is differentiable on $(a,b)$ with derivative $f$. Moreover it is also continuous on $[a,b]$.

Now if the only condition $F$ satisfies is that $F’=f$ on $(a,b)$ then $F$ need not be continuous at $a$ and $b$. However we know that there exists at least one continuous anti derivative $h$. We can therefore require that an anti derivative is continuous at its end points for it to be an anti derivative.